# `operator type&` confusion

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast

I have user-defined type:

```
class String::CharProxy
{
public:
    const char* operator&() const;
    char* operator&();
    operator char() const;
    operator char&();
};
```

The problem is when I'm trying to perform some explicit casts, the wrong operator is called:

```
CharProxy p(...);
static_cast<char>(p); // operator char&() call instead of operator char() const
```

I want `operator char() const` to be called when casting to `char` and `operator char&()` - when casting to `char&` only.

Could anyone explain how this mechanism works? Am I mistaken anywhere?

Comment: "*char* operator&();*" Overloading `operator&` is a really bad idea. It causes a lot of problems and solves basically nothing.

Comment: Change `CharProxy p(...);` to `CharProxy const p(...);`

Comment: @NicolBolas That's right, but that doesn't really relate to the question. I have to implement it on my teacher's demand. I will edit the question.

Comment: @CapyMaths: "*That's right, but that doesn't really relate to the question.*" I know; that's why it was a comment.

Comment: if it's still cast to `char`, I don't see what's wrong?

Comment: @Eljay but if I need to use exactly `CharProxy p(...);` ? Why non-constantness requires `operator char&()` call?

Comment: @appleapple if I understand you, it is not the cast to `char`, it is cast to `char&`. Moreover, `operator char() const` and `operator char&()` have completely different logic. It's extremely important to call the right one in that case.

Comment: @CapyMaths then the overload is flawed then. They should return same value (regardless of const/ref).

Comment: @appleapple how to achieve that?

Comment: @CapyMaths make them not have completely different logic?

Comment: @appleapple Thank you, I've got your point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `static_cast`, both `operator char() const` and `operator char&()` are candidate functions as per [over.match.conv] because both `char` and `char&` are convertible to `char` via a standard conversion sequence.

Between the two functions, the compiler then decides by standard overload resolution rules. In these, `operator char&()` is found to be a better fit because its implicit `this` parameter has the same cv-qualifiers as the object you're passing into it (that is: there is no `const` qualifier on `p`). You can explicitly call the other operator with

```
static_cast<char>(static_cast<CharProxy const &>(p));
```

But in more realistic terms: 1. user-defined conversion functions are a hornets' nest that are best avoided 99% of the time, and 2. if your `operator char() const` has so different semantics from your `operator char&()` that you cannot use the latter where you can use the former, that seems like a very dangerous thing you're building there. Certainly it's not POLA-compliant.

Comment: Yep, you're right. It's a good example of how not to code :)

Answer (score 3):

There are two competing overloads. But neither of them is an exact match. The second overload can be called, but it requires doing a standard conversion of the resulting `char&` into a `char`. The first overload can also be called, but that requires doing a conversion of a reference to `p` from `CharProxy&` to `CharProxy const&`.

Due to various conflict resolution stuff in overload resolution, the former conversion is considered a better fit than the latter.

There's not much you can do about it, nor is there much you *should* do about it. There should be no functional difference between which one gets called in this circumstance, as the returned reference ought to refer to a `char` with the same value that would have been returned by the other one.